# send a data and image with ajax post to php and later to mysql blob

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, blob

I have a problem when saving an image on the database. This image is located on the canvans, but I can not upload it on the database.
The image is saved on the database using a blog variable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Registro</title>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/webcam.js"></script>



</head>

<body>

    <div>
    <video id="player" autoplay="true" width="200"  height="100"></video>
    </div>


        <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" id="enviarimagenes" name="enviarimagenes" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

            <br><label>Primer nombre</label></br>
            <input name="p_nombre" id="p_nombre" type="text" maxlength="15" />
            <br><label>Segundo nombre</label></br>
            <input name="s_nombre" id="s_nombre" type="text" maxlength="15" />
            <br><label>Primer apellido</label></br>
            <input name="p_apellido" id="p_apellido" type="text" maxlength="15" />
            <br><label>Segundo apellido</label></br>
            <input name="s_apellido" id="s_apellido" type="text" maxlength="15" />
            <br><label>Tipo dentificación</label></br>
            <select name="tipoindetificacion" id="tipoindetificacion">
                <option value=1 >Cédula de cuidadania</option>
                <option value=2 >Tarjeta de identidad</option>
                <option value=3 >Cédula de extanjería</option>
            </select>
            <br><label>Identificación</label></br>
            <input name="identificaion" id="identificacion" type="text" maxlength="25" />
            <br><label>Apartamento a visitar</label></br>
            <br><select name="apartamento" id="apartamento"></select></br>
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </form>

        <div>
            <input id="tfoto" type="button" onclick = "takepicture()" value="Tomar foto" /> 
        </div>

        <div>
          <input name="other" id="other" type="button" value="Enviar" onclick="registrar()" />
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

my script webcam.js is:

```
(function(){

  cargarapartamentos();
  var mediaOptions = { audio: false, video: true };


  if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia;
  }

  if (!navigator.getUserMedia){
    alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
  }

  navigator.getUserMedia(mediaOptions, success, function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });

  function success(stream){
    var video = document.querySelector("#player");
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

  }

})()

function takepicture() {

  var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var video   = document.getElementById('player');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var videowidth   = video.videoWidth;
  var videoheight  = video.videoHeight;

  canvas.width = videowidth;
  canvas.height = videoheight;

  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, videowidth, videoheight);

};


function registrar(){

  var fecha_hora = Date();
  var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imagenurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",0.8);
      imagenurl = imagenurl.substr(22, imagenurl.length);



var param = { p_nombre:document.getElementById('p_nombre').value, 
              s_nombre:document.getElementById('s_nombre').value,
              p_apellido:document.getElementById('p_apellido').value,
              s_apellido:document.getElementById('s_apellido').value,
              tipoindetificacion:document.getElementById('tipoindetificacion').value,
              identificacion:document.getElementById('identificacion').value,
              fecha_hora_in:fecha_hora,
              imagen_jpeg:imagenurl,
              apartamento:document.getElementById('apartamento').value};

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "http://localhost/registroInconjunto/phps/insertarregistro.php",
      data: param,
      dataType: 'text'
    }).done(function(data) {

      alert(data);

    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
              console.log(xhr.statusText);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(error);
    }).always(function() {
              alert("se ejecutó la funcion registrar.");
    });

};


function cargarapartamentos(){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost/registroInconjunto/phps/buscarapartamentos.php",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {

      $.each(data, function(i, item) {

        var elemento = document.getElementById('apartamento');
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = item.id_apartamento;
        option.text = item.apartolugar;
        elemento.add(option);

      });

    }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
              console.log(xhr.statusText);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(error);
    }).always(function() {
              // called after done or fail
    });

};
```

whem the page is opened, the script charge in the select "apartamento" a list of dates, and open the webcam, the funtion takepicture take a picture and put this on a Canvas

the database is call `registro_conjuntos` and hava a table registro_entrada_personas

```
CREATE TABLE `registro_entrada_personas` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'id de tabla',
  `apartamento` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'numero del apartamento',
  `p_nombre` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_nombre` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `p_apellido` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `s_apellido` text COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo_indentificacion` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'cc, ti, ce, etc',
  `indentificacion` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha_hora_in` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'hora de entrada',
  `imagen_jpeg` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'imagen tomada'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci COMMENT='tabla registro de entrada visitantes';
```

the php is:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


$p_nombre = $_POST['p_nombre'];
$s_nombre = $_POST['s_nombre'];
$p_apellido = $_POST['p_apellido'];
$s_apellido = $_POST['s_apellido'];
$tipoindetificacion = $_POST['tipoindetificacion'];
$identificacion = $_POST['identificacion'];
$fecha_hora_in = $_POST['fecha_hora_in'];
$imagen_jpeg = $_POST['imagen_jpeg'];
$apartamento = $_POST['apartamento'];


$conexion = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "xxx", "xxxxx", "registro_conjuntos");



    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();

    }else{

        $fecha_hora_in = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");

        $sentenciaInsertar = "INSERT INTO `registro_entrada_personas` (`id`, `apartamento`, `p_nombre`, `s_nombre`, `p_apellido`, `s_apellido`, `tipo_indentificacion`, `indentificacion`, `fecha_hora_in`, `imagen_jpeg`) VALUES (NULL, '{$apartamento}', '{$p_nombre}', '{$s_nombre}', '{$p_apellido}', '$s_apellido', '{$tipoindetificacion}', '{$identificacion}', '{$fecha_hora_in}', '{$dataimagen}')";

        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sentenciaInsertar);

        if ($resultado) {
            echo $imagen_jpeg;
        } else {
            echo "Error Php: " + mysqli_error($conexion);
        }           
        $close = mysqli_close($conexion);
    }

?>
```

The data is stored in the table but the encoded image does not, I have tried to store without removing the "data: image / png; base64," from the header of the imageurl variable and which I do with imagenurl.substr (22, imagenurl.length) ; however the variable is stored in the table but unformatted and is not displayed by phpmyadmin

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: That image data you're posting isn't binary data, it's just text (base64 encoded binary data) so there's no need to store it as a blob. If you want to store it as a blob (since it takes less space), then you should decode it before saving. But you should use Prepare Statements to make sure that any invalid chars won't be an issue (and to protect yourself against sql injection attacks)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.